# Is there a payroll management software that integrates with employee schedules?

Tags: business-intelligence

I am looking for a new solution for my fast growing company, we've recently hired our first team and we're looking for a solution that will:

Allow me to schedule employee working hours

Track when the employee is working (are they completing their hours?)

Pay them according to the hours worked

If one solution can do all of this, I'd be elated! But, I am happy to use a combination of solutions if need be. I've heard of TSheets, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made an account just to reply to this, as I am in HR and I'm familiar with this field.

Depending on the size of your organization, you have a few options. I like to recommend [Deputy](https://deputy.com) as a time-clock solution for small to large businesses. This is due to its pricing (some of the options only make sense for large businesses and don't scale down), and feedback from employees (they like Deputy's employee interface).

If you are a corporate, then you will likely have a custom hodge podge of solutions due to inflexible policies. It's lucky that you're asking now before you get to the slow moving corporate giant stage!